# Django - ModelForm invalid syntax error

Tags: django, django-forms

it is simple.

here is my Profile Model :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      owner = models.OneToOneField(User)
      slogan = models.TextField(null=True)
      twitter = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null=True)
      web_site = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
      email = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null=True)

      def create_user(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
          if created:
              Profile.objects.create(owner=instance)

          post_save.connect(create_user, sender=User)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.email
```

and ModelForm:

```
class profile_form(ModelForm):
      slogan   = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Site Sloganı','rows':'4',}))
      #title    = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Site Başlığı',}))
      email    = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'E-Mail Adresi',}))
      twitter  = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Twitter Adresi',}))
      web_site = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Web Siteniz',})

      class Meta:
          model = Profile
```

when i try to import blog.forms it throws invalid syntax error in line 50 which includes 'class Meta'.

there were nothing like that. it has just shown.

thank you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
web_site = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Web Siteniz',})
```

it is missing a closing paranthesis

add a `)` at the end.

So it would change to

```
web_site = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Web Siteniz',}))
```

Comment: oh! i am just a new vi user. sometimes i forget to switch insert mode :)